# Unable to establish a connection with ingress in GKE which is using GitlabCI

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, integration-testing, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to run the Docker images from gitlab-registry in Google Kubernetes Engine in a cluster and have traffic flow through ingress nginx controller. I am not able to achieve it. 
Here is the proper explanation. 
I build a pipeline using gitlab ci/cd and each time a pipeline is a success it pushes a docker image to gitlab registry. 
Now I want to test that images stored in the gitlab registry. I need to pull them and run containers from that images in the kubernetes cluster in Google Kubernetes Engine. I tried a lot of ways but a few errors keep coming. for example:`/built_app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313
                                                throw(ex);
                                                ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [cluster1-shard-00-02-iqf6c.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connection 5 to cluster1-shard-00-02-iqf6c.mongodb.net:27017 timed out]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:199:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)`

I tried to set the environmental variables as a secret in the kubernetes cluster and used them. and also I created one more secret to use it for pulling images from the private gitlab registry.

I also have a Nginx-ingress-controller setup by the gitlab while integrated the kubernetes cluster with Gitlab.

I want to connect and test these docker images from the internet using the Ingress and the GKE. 
I am stuck here without any idea. Any help would be great for a beginner like me.

I have the kubernetes cluster integrated with gitlab CI and this integration have already installed some apps like ingress-nginx-controller, gitlab-runner and other on my cluster in GKE.

Here I am attaching the YAML files used in GKE.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-one
  namespace: gitlab-managed-apps
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mycontainer
        image: my-image-from-private-gitlab-registry
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: MONGO_URL
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: envisec
              key: MONGO_URL
        - name: ROOT_URL
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: envisec
              key: ROOT_URL
        - name: PORT
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: envisec
              key: PORT
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: myreg

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-service
  namespace: gitlab-managed-apps
  labels:
    app : myapp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: myapp
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingress
  namespace: gitlab-managed-apps
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
  paths:
  - path: /hello
    backend:
      serviceName: myapp-service
      servicePort: 80
```

these are the yaml fileS which I've been using. The mongodb which we use use is hosted on another service. The connection is not being made with mongoDB and I am stuck here. I am stuck and any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Can you share manifest *.yaml files for K8s ingress nginx controller, deployment, etc.?

Comment: @mk_sta sure I will share them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, GKE gives you the possibility to create [HTTP(S) Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/), once you deploy the Ingress resource on Kubernetes cluster. You might also need to switch the nested Pod service to `NodePort`, this is in order to route the network traffic to the application. You can check the External IP address for Load Balancer by the following command:

`kubectl get ingress myapp-ingress`

Based on the configuration that you have provided, I would suggest replacing `LoadBalancer` with `NodePort` parameter. You can get more information in the Official Google Cloud [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer).

Comment: I tried changing the type from LoadBalancer to NodePort but that does not help.